# SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status while vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, nfs

I have added debian os to vagrant, then run vagrant up command, but it will throw the following error.

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.56.1:'/u01/ChennaiBox/mage2_vagrant' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Next i added /etc/sudoers

```
   vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   Defaults:vagrant !requiretty
```

This is My Syn_Folder code in vagrantfile:

```
    if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]
  else
#    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"] }

     config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]

    #rsync_args = ['--verbose', '--archive', '-z']
    #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",
    #  rsync__args: rsync_args, rsync__exclude: ['.vagrant/'], rsync__auto: true, type: 'rsync'

  end
```

Now also throw same error, suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: I am wondering for down vote, please mention why this question not fit because I need to edit as per your suggestion.

Comment: I agree, down vote should come with a mandatory comment ! can you highlight the sync_folder section of your Vagrantfile, you have nfs right ? did you try to share without nfs to see if you have the same issue

Comment: @Frédéric Henri i update my question , suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: try the syntax `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]`

Comment: @Frédéric Henri     now, throw this error man,              mount -o 'dmode=777,fmode=777' 192.168.56.1:'/u01/ChennaiBox/mage2_vagrant' /vagrant

Comment: I update my syn.folder code in question

Comment: my vagrant version is 1.8 ,  any problem for this syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my Problem to stop firewall

Using follwing command:

```
   systemctl stop firewalld
```

Its worked for me.

Comment: The problem was the same on OSX, the firewall blocked!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem suddelny vagrant up doesn't work any more and the error msg  "mount.nfs: Connection timed out". was shown
i just remove the old version of vagrant and download the new version "2.2.4"